# Unexpected result stored in attribute populated by DXL script

Tags: ibm-doors

I'm now the maintainer for a bunch of dxl scripts, and I am in the process of testing them all.

The script in question formats multiple strings into a buffer, then converts back to a string. This string is then concatenated with another string, and then stored in an attribute. The code is below (variable names and number of function parameters have been sanitised FYI):

```
string formatForField(string s1, string s2){
    Buffer buff = create();

    buff += s1 
    buff += "\n";
    buff += s2;

    string formattedString = tempStringOf(buff);
    delete(buff);
    return formattedString;
}

void alterField(string inputString1, string inputString2){
    string formattedChange = formatForField(inputString1, inputString2);
    string oldValue = currentObject."Attribute Name";

    if (oldValue != "") {
        oldValue = oldValue "\n---\n";
    }

    string newValue = oldValue formattedChange;
    currentObject."Attribute Name" = newValue;
}
```

The problem is that occasionally instead of the expected result, the current objects's value of "Attribute Name" has □ appended onto the previous value.

If for example, the value of `(current object)."Attribute Name` is `"Lorem Ipsum"` and after running the script, the expected value of `(current object)."Attribute Name` is:

```
Lorem Ipsum
---
inputString1
inputString2
```

Then occasionally, the value of `(current object)."Attribute Name` will actually be:

```
Lorem Ipsum
---
□
```

I've not been able to locate any similar reported issues online, so I'm posting here. I'm not sure what is happening here, as 99% of the time the script provides the expected output. Interestingly, if the attribute contains the white square after running the script, running the script again with the same input will result in the expected output...

Edit: [This image shows the white square I am on about, as it doesn't seem to show up in the live post view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6n6E.png)

Extra Edit: Upon further inspection, I've found that sometimes additional random characters are included. [The right column is supposed to contain text, not the random characters it does contain.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwiF1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realised the error. The buff was being deleted just after calling
tempStringOf and so the memory being referenced was deallocated, causing the weirdness. Silly mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I state the obvious here, but I'm not really sure where the problem exactly lies. From what I read, alterField has the following characteristica.

Expected input are two strings. Precondition: both of them must have a value.
The function checks whether the attribute "Attribute Name" already has a value. If so, the old value shall be preserved and the two strings shall be added to the old value, separated by a line of dashes. The two strings are concatenated by a carriage return.

So, after starting the following script

```
Object currentObject = first
currentObject."Attribute Name" = "good morning"
String partOne = "good"
String partTwo = "evening"
alterField (partOne, partTwo)
alterField (partOne, partTwo)
alterField (partOne, partTwo)
```

the attribute "Attribute Name" of the first object of the Module will have the following content:

```
good morning
---
good
evening
---
good
evening
---
good
evening
```

If the precondition is not met and partOne is empty (""), partTwo is "evening", then after three calls of alterField the attribute will look like this:

```
good morning
---

evening
---

evening
---

evening
```

The question is: what do you expect to happen?

Comment: what you're describing is the desired output, and what happens 99% of the time. The problem that I am having is occasionally the script will append a white square (which i am just realising only shows up whilst I'm editing the post. I will add a screen shot.

Comment: the screen shot is in the original post

Comment: the script excerpt itself is OK, I cannot find any flaw. So, most probably the problem must lie elsewhere, at the place where "alterField" is called, or to be more precise, the place where `inputString1`and `inputString2` get their values. If these strings come from other objects' attributes, perhaps someone inserted such a faulty value into the attribute? Or for whatever reasons, in some cases, `inputString1/2` contain some part of an OLE string? or of some picture? some calculated value? the white square is often a replacement character for characters with an illegal code point.

Comment: Thanks @Mike, I suspected it might have been one of those but hoped someone had encountered something similar. Thanks for taking the time, I appreciate it.